# Interaction terms in statistical modelling vs. independent variables

Tags: statistics, interaction

this is a nice [example](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-interactions-in-regression/) of usage of interaction terms in statistical modelling:

> "The example from Interpreting Regression Coefficients was a model of
>   the height of a shrub (Height) based on the amount of bacteria in the
>   soil (Bacteria) and whether the shrub is located in partial or full
>   sun (Sun). Height is measured in cm, Bacteria is measured in thousand
>   per ml of soil, and Sun = 0 if the plant is in partial sun and Sun = 1
>   if the plant is in full sun. The regression equation was estimated as
>   follows:
>
> Height = 42 + 2.3*Bacteria + 11*Sun
>
> It would be useful to add an interaction term to the model if we
>   wanted to test the hypothesis that the relationship between the amount
>   of bacteria in the soil on the height of the shrub was different in
>   full sun than in partial sun.
>
> One possibility is that in full sun, plants with more bacteria in the
>   soil tend to be taller, whereas in partial sun, plants with more
>   bacteria in the soil are shorter. Another possibility is that plants
>   with more bacteria in the soil tend to be taller in both full and
>   partial sun, but that the relationship is much more dramatic in full
>   than in partial sun."

What I do not understand completely is when to use this interaction term? Couldn't I simply use the variable sun as an another independent variable in multiple regression, instead of as an interaction term? When to use something as an interaction term, and when as a separate independent variable?

Comment: Use an interaction term when you want to test a conditional relationship like your statement "It would be useful to add an interaction term to the model if we wanted to test the hypothesis that the relationship between the amount of bacteria in the soil on the height of the shrub was different in full sun than in partial sun." If you do not have this interaction term (only a main effect) in your model, then you cannot test whether the effect of bacteria and its association with height changes as a function of sun exposure or vice versa.

Comment: Forgot to mention: The model as is, the coefficients are interpreted as the effect of bacteria on height (holding sun exposure constant) and the effect of sun exposure on height (holding bacteria level constant). There are no conditional effect interpretations without first having the interaction term in the model